# When did Pucci reset the universe?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

Does anyone know the specific date or time when Pucci reset the universe? Or anything similar like the month and year it happened?

Answer (score 0):

The universe has been reset at the singulary point, so **infinity**.

What you are looking for is probably when Pucci started speeding up the universe. That is  **March 21st, 2012**, one day before the new moon on March 22nd, 2012.

It is written on the intro to Stone Ocean chapter 157 "Made in Heaven Part 9".

[image: Cape Canaveral Visitor Center (Time stars to speed up March 21st, 2012)]

Answer (score 0):

No, because Pucci didn't reset the universe in a certain time. He sped up time so much that at some point, the amount of time to be sped up was infinite, and therefore he sped up time until there was no time left, bypassing infinity. He reset the universe outside the bounds of time.